# Combine prefetch_related and pandas

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, django-orm

I have a problem with converting a queryset with prefetch_related to a dataframe.

```
qs = Model1.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('model_2', 
    queryset=Model2.all_objects.all(), to_attr='new_attr'))
```

When I do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list(records.values()))
print(df.columns.to_list())
```

I don't see a column with name 'new_attr'.
Maybe exist a way to add this column to a dataframe? Maybe like string, if i do something like that:

```
import json 
json.dumps(Model2.all_objects.values())
```

Comment: `.values()` will not fetch related objects. It will thus ignore `prefetch_related`, etc.

Comment: Hmm.. what should I do?